# Drupal page sending a request (curl) to a subdomain site: fails while same url works from client

Tags: php, curl, cookies, request

I'm trying to connect two of our websites with each other. First one sends a request to the other one which should reply to it. However, when doing this from backend it fails and from client it works fine.

There's a login required and these parameters are sent within request. From debug log I can see that curl follows the different redirections returned from the other site but it always ends up to the login page.

Is this related to cookies or what? How the backend could get a cookie to be able behave as logged in? Or can I use other cookies under same domain?

I've tried to use these configurations along with different temp files and variables:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);

but these always land on error 
    expect parameter 1 to be resource, null given.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone would be able to help you without some bit of code.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this

If the cookie is generated from script, then you can send the cookie manually along with the cookie from the file(using cookie-file option). For example:

## sending manually set cookie

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: test=cookie"));

## sending cookies from file

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
In this case curl will send your defined cookie along with the cookies from the file.

If the cookie is generated through javascrript, then you have to trace it out how its generated and then you can send it using the above method(through http-header).

The utma utmc, utmz are seen when cookies are sent from Mozilla. You shouldn't bet worry about these things anymore.

Finally, the way you are doing is alright. Just make sure you are using absolute path for the file names(i.e. /var/dir/cookie.txt) instead of relative one.

Always enable the verbose mode when working with curl. It will help you a lot on tracing the requests. Also it will save lot of your times.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this well based answer. I'd like to add few more notes this issue.

First of all the url that I'm using consists of regular parameter e.g. a=b but it also has a returnurl parameter with urlencoded value that is used by the receiving webservice to redirect.

Secondly the curl debug shows that it is redirected three times and the receiving webservice is sending set-cookie headers. How can I use this with curl?